# From Hex String to signed int

Tags: android, int, hex

In the app that I'm developing, first of all, I do a conversion from a decimal value to an hex string.

For example, I convert the int value **-100000** to it's hex value:

```
hex_value = Integer.toHexString (-100000)
```

And I get this:

```
hex_value = FFFE7960
```

Now, I need to do the inverse conversion. I get the **FFFE7960** hex value and I need to convert it to **-100000** again, for this I use:

```
int_value = Integer.parseInt(hex_value,16)
```

But instead of getting **-100000**, I get **4294867296**.

So, instead of getting the signed int value, I'm getting a unsigned value that causes an error on my app.

How can I do it to get the desired value?

**UPDATE - FULL CODE**

This is the string that I receive via bluetooth:

```
s = "2b 00 ff fe 79 60"
```

With the StringTokenizer I split it:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(s," ");
String one = tokens.nextToken();
String two = tokens.nextToken();
String three = tokens.nextToken();
String four = tokens.nextToken();
String five = tokens.nextToken();
String six = tokens.nextToken();

received_hexValue = three + four + five + six;
```

So, **received_hexValue = "fffe7960"**

Now, I make the conversion that I need:

```
int_value_receive = (int)Long.parseLong(received_hexValue, 16);
int_value_receive = -200000 - int_value_receive;
newIntValue = (int_value_receive * 100) / (200000 * (-1));
```

In the first line, when converting from hex to int, the debugger throws me a Long.invalidLong(String) error, and in the logcat, shows the error commented: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: At which line of code `NPE` is?

Comment: When doing this: `int_value_receive = (int)Long.parseLong(received_hexValue, 16);`

Comment: But I posted my answer in comment when I run your code. I am not getting any type of error.. :/

Comment: Ok, that was the thing. It was introducing empty spaces after the hex string, so, doing a `received_hexValue = received_hexValue.trim()` it's solved!

Comment: and you haven't posted that code here.. :) which prevent me from error. Ha ha.. :P

Comment: Sorry Chintan, what code do you reffer to? I don't know how I was getting those empty chars in the string. I've realized about it, because when analizing the cause of the error in the logcat, I've seen that there where strange characters after the hex values, but don't ask me how they have getted there... xD

Comment: Just chill. Never mind.. Won't ask.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using following code.

```
String hex_value = Integer.toHexString(-100000);
Log.d("Home", "Hex : " + hex_value);

int int_value = (int) Long.parseLong(hex_value, 16);
Log.d("Home", "Int : " + int_value);
```

This code will first create long value `4294867296` and then will return you `-100000` as output.

**Edit**

Your code is like

```
String s = "2b 00 ff fe 79 60";
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");
String one = tokens.nextToken();
String two = tokens.nextToken();
String three = tokens.nextToken();
String four = tokens.nextToken();
String five = tokens.nextToken();
String six = tokens.nextToken();

String received_hexValue = three + four + five + six;

Log.d("Home", "Hex : " + received_hexValue);

//to get sub string of your length, pass start and end offset
Log.d("Home", "SubString Hex : " +received_hexValue.substring(0, 8));

int int_value_receive = (int) Long.parseLong(received_hexValue, 16);
Log.d("Home", "Old Int : " + int_value_receive);
int_value_receive = -200000 - int_value_receive;
Log.d("Home", "Int : " + int_value_receive);
int newIntValue = (int_value_receive * 100) / (200000 * (-1));
Log.d("Home", "New Int : " + newIntValue);
```

**Output**

09-03 16:22:37.421: DEBUG/Home(28973): Hex : fffe7960
09-03 16:22:37.421: DEBUG/Home(28973): Old Int : -100000
09-03 16:22:37.421: DEBUG/Home(28973): Int : -100000
09-03 16:22:37.421: DEBUG/Home(28973): New Int : 50

Comment: I'm just using it and I'm still getting this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "fffe7960 (following to this appears an unknow character several times)`

Comment: are you changing your hex code in between? I retry my code with your commented hex code and i am not getting any error my friend. :)

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code where you can see if there is something wrong

Comment: Are you getting error? I am getting following logs. `09-03 16:08:48.441: DEBUG/Home(27598): Old Int : -100000`
`09-03 16:08:48.441: DEBUG/Home(27598): Int : -100000`
`09-03 16:08:48.451: DEBUG/Home(27598): New Int : 50`

Comment: The for you is working fine. I think maybe could be because for any reason, the `received_hexValue` string is getting more values or empty spaces after the hex value. How can I tell to the hex string to be only as long as the hex value that i set?

Comment: @masmic_87, I think you can use `received_hexValue.substring(0, 8))`;

Comment: Usually using `.trim()` I'm getting the right result. Do you think is more correct to use the `.substring` or the `.trim()`?

Comment: Um...trim will only remove spaces if i am not wrong.. that will not remove those chars which you said those entered in your hex. Though substring will only cut down those chars from your string what you have provided offsets.. So yes.. sub string will be better to use instead of trim.. :)